# Use ssh_authorized_keys external cookbook with Amazon OpsWorks

Tags: chef-infra, aws-opsworks

Being a Chef newbie I have a hard time to use [ssh_authorized_keys](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/ssh_authorized_keys) with Amazon OpsWorks. When firing up a new instance I get the following error:

```
[2016-07-01T10:02:37+00:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 412 Precondition Failed: 
No such cookbook: ssh_authorized_keys

================================================================================
Error Resolving Cookbooks for Run List:
================================================================================

Missing Cookbooks:
------------------
No such cookbook: ssh_authorized_keys

Expanded Run List:
------------------
* chef-provisioning::default
```

What do I have to change to make it work?

I use the following configs:

**Berksfile**

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'
cookbook 'ssh_authorized_keys', '~> 0.3.0'
```

**metadata.rb**

```
name 'chef-provisioning'
maintainer 'abc'
maintainer_email 'alice@example.com'
license 'all_rights'
description 'Installs/Configures chef-provisioning'
long_description 'Installs/Configures chef-provisioning'
version '0.1.0'
depends 'ssh_authorized_keys'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is directory structure. The `ssh_authorized_keys` cookbook has to be in the same directory as our own cookbook `ops-works` (which holds the normal recipies).

```
$ tree -d
.
├── ops-works
│   ├── recipes
│   ├── spec
│   │   └── unit
│   │       └── recipes
│   └── test
│       └── integration
│           ├── default
│           │   └── serverspec
│           └── helpers
│               └── serverspec
└── ssh_authorized_keys
    ├── attributes
    ├── definitions
    ├── libraries
    └── templates
        └── default
```

**Berksfile**

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'
cookbook 'ssh_authorized_keys'
```

I'd advise to use `berks vendor` and having a look at 
[Failing To Find Chef Community Cookbooks Using Chef 12 On AWS Opsworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36242345/failing-to-find-chef-community-cookbooks-using-chef-12-on-aws-opsworks)